# Why doesn't my statement change and add attributes for anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the value of anchor tag and also add new attributes but it does not seem to work.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0]
  .getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
  .attr({ 
    href: '#', 
    data: 'xyz', 
    name: 'test'
  });
```

Comment: @NegiRox, there's nothing inherently wrong with that. In this case the results are unexpected, though.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're attempting to use a jQuery method on a native DOM element. My guess is that your browser's throwing an error indicating such.

Instead, use jQuery syntax to create an actual jQuery object:

```
$('.button a').attr({ ... });
```

This has the bonus benefit of being a fraction as long.

In case you actually need to select the first of the elements jQuery grabs with that selector, use `first()`:

```
$('.button a').first().attr({ ... });
```

This filters the jQuery object into a new one without converting to a native DOM element. It's fragile, however, because it depends on your markup for accurate selection. I'd prefer to add another class to that button or target an ancestor element for specificity:

```
$('.button.my-extra-class a').attr({ ... });
```

Comment: the `[0]` in his question mean he needs first element no ?

Comment: @JaxTeller possibly. Or alternatively just added the `[0]` to work with the collection knowing there's only ever one element

Comment: No. There are other ways of selecting one element in a jQuery object without converting to a native DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

I've put together an example of how you can set attributes.

```js
let link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

link.setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.com");
link.setAttribute("data", "xyz");
link.setAttribute("data-name", "test");
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">A link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaNZKd

Here's some more info on setting attributes: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: Good alternative answer, but I prefer [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button")
    .first()
    .find("a")
    .first()
    .attr('href', '@')
    .attr('data', 'xyz')
    .attr('name', 'test');
```

What this means is that you're getting the first `<button>`, then the first `<a>` within that button, and then assigning the data.

Based on your code, I assume this is what you want.

Comment: I wouldn't think the second `first()` would ever be needed, and it's generally best to combine instances of `attr()` as the OP has already done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try querySelectorAll

```js
     let anchor = document.querySelectorAll('a.button')[0];

     anchor.setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.com");
```

```html
     <a href="#" class="button">A link - will be affected</a><br/>
     <a href="#" class="button">B link - not affected</a><br/>
     <a href="#">C link - not affected</a><br/>
     <a href="#">D link - not affected</a><br/>
```